# What would you call "When you think of someone all the time?"

Tags: american-english

I always keep thinking about one girl and I want to use a word except **love**.
I want to tell her that I'm suffering from her addiction in a word which she may have never heard of.

Comment: It is sometimes referred to as "mooning over" someone.  "He was mooning over the young lady he'd met at the party."

Comment: @HotLicks I think this deserves to be posted as an answer

Answer (score 3):

The classic word here is "[obsess](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsess)" (MW, transitive verb).

> to haunt or excessively preoccupy the mind of

Be aware, however, that to a native English speaker, this may be perceived as having positive or negative connotations.

Comment: *Obsessed* works for me, based on personal experience.

Comment: @RichardKayser If you say so, Rich. However, my personal obsessions in this regard have a tendency to verge on the pathological, so I have changed life's game plan to DIY tiddlywinks instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's called *infatuation*.

> **Infatuation** *noun*
> An intense but short-lived passion or admiration for someone or something:
> [mass noun] ‘the thrill of infatuation’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/infatuation)
>
> **Infatuation** or **being smitten** is the state of being carried away by an unreasoned passion.
> [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infatuation) (emphasis in original)

In your sample sentence, you're "suffering from *infatuation*". I make no guarantees about how well this phrasing would be received, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about *fixate* (verb) or *fixation* (noun)?

M-W:

> [*fixate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fixate): **to
>   focus or concentrate one's** gaze or **attention** intently or **obsessively** [emphasis added]
>
> [*fixation*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fixation): an
>   obsessive or unhealthy preoccupation or attachment

Comment: _fixation_ implies "unhealthy", which doesn't really seem what OP wants. At least, I wouldn't flirt with someone by saying "I have an unhealthy and obsessive attachment for you"

Comment: @Irhala Note that the definition says *or*. *Fixation* is not necessarily negative.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider ***beguiled***.
You may then say:

> I am ***beguiled*** by you.

ODO:

> **[beguile](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/beguile)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Charm or enchant (someone), often in a deceptive way:
>
> ‘Her smile beguiled Paul, and for a very brief second he forgot what
>   he was supposed to do.’
>
> ‘When Juliette is beguiled by the charms of Paris, Jean believes he
>   has lost her.’

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that no one has suggested ***mooning*** as an answer.  It's been popular a term as long as I can remember and apparently still is, based on [Ngram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mooning+over&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmooning%20over%3B%2Cc0).  Basically, one might say that a boy is "mooning over" a girl (or vice-versa), when he can't get her out of his mind and is thinking of her (and probably "lusting" for her, in a teenage way) most of his waking hours (and especially when trying to go to sleep at night).

And, based on the [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mooning%20over%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1996,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en), it appears that "mooning over" is often used in a sort of metaphorical sense to mean obsessing over some object or concept.

Answer (score 0):

It's not one word, but the phrase that most English speakers might use there is:

**I can't get you out of my mind.**

Comment: Or as Kylie sings https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Can't_Get_You_Out_of_My_Head

Answer (score 0):

How about *entranced*?

M-W:

> [*entrance*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entranced): to
>   carry away with delight, wonder, or rapture

Example:

> I am entranced by you. I think about you constantly, all day and night.

Answer (score 0):

How about *stuck on*?

The Free Dictionary:

> [*stuck on someone or
>   something*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stuck+on): **in love
>   with someone** or something; **entranced with someone** or something
>   [emphasis added]

Example:

> I'm stuck on you. I think about you every moment of every waking day.